# How to pass more than two parameters in a queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I hope my question is understood

For example, I have this model

```
class Area(models.Model):
  area_id = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.CharField()
  last_name = models.CharField()
  short_name = models.CharField()
```

I want to make a query with several parameters

If I do not find the first one, look for it for the second and so with the third

```
filter_areas = Area.objects.filter(area_id=3 | name='area_name' | short_name='are')
```

Like to an or |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object here:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Area.objects.filter(Q(area_id=1)| Q(name='name') | Q(short_name='are'))
```